# My published app on google play shows an android file when users download it. How can i fix this?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-games

I finally got my game published on the Google play store but when users download the app it can't open and it shows an android studio file instead of my game.I don't know where I went wrong but I think I might have done some done something on android studio. I appreciate any advice, thanks.

[image: picture of what it looks like.]

[image: picture of what it's supposed to look like.]

Comment: Check your manifest. Make sure that your application id is correct. If you have multiple modules make sure that they have `tools:replace="android:name"` specified in their Manifest files.

Comment: I looked at the manifest but i'm not seeing the tools:replace="android:name"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The app icon** is set as `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"` in `application` section in AndroidManifest.xml . Check out all mipmap folders and update the icon to the one you need (It's currently showing default icon from mipmap-anydpi-v26 folder which is created when you create a project in AndroidStudio).

**The app name** is a label from your launcher Activity. In AndroidManifest.xml find an activity with intent-filter `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` and set a label you need `android:label="@string/app_name"`.

**The app can't be opened** because of some issue in your code. To keep track of crash issues you can use tools like [Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started#android).